# How to pass the index from a widget to another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi i have Pageview with `weekIndex` which show me the days of the week and I need to pass `weekIndex` to another widget
this is my code for the Pageview:

```
Expanded(
                        child: PageView.builder(
                          controller: _pageController,
                          itemBuilder: (context, weekIndex) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount: 7,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                                      int milliseconds = now
                                              .millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                                          (now.weekday - 1) *
                                              24 *
                                              60 *
                                              60 *
                                              1000 +
                                          weekIndex * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                                          index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

and I need to pass weekIndex to this widget:

```
GridView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 7,
                          ),
                          itemCount: 20,
                          itemBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                            int milliseconds = now
                                .millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                                (now.weekday - 1) *
                                    24 *
                                    60 *
                                    60 *
                                    1000 +
                                weekIndex * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +// here I need to pass the weekIndex
                                index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

                            DateTime dayDateTime =
                            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                milliseconds);
                            int monthIndex = dayDateTime.month - 1;
```

Comment: it depends how they are interlinked!

Answer (score 0):

take another variable `int temp = 0` inside the `PageView.builder` in the `itemBuilder` set `temp = weekIndex`,
If you give the full code it would be better to say how to do it, if the `GridView` is inside the `PageView` then you can access `weekIndex` directly. If it is outside its outside then declaring another variable will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inherited widget to update variables without setState